# CEFSharp RegisterJsObject reference error

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I know this question has been beaten to death with this library but despite the examples available, I'm having a hard time getting Javascript bindings to work with WPF.

I'm using CefSharp.Common 37.0.0
The Javascript error that I'm getting is: **Uncaught ReferenceError: myClass is not defined**

Below, you will find a small code example.  I feel like this is fairly straight forward.  Let me know if anybody needs additional information.  Thanks.

Here is my HTML / JS logic

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test(){

                MyClass.myFunc();
            }
        </script>        
    </head>

    <body>
        This is a cat
        <button id='testBtn' onclick="test();" type="button">Meow</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

C# / .NET Logic

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace HTML5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser.Loaded += webBrowser_Loaded;
        }

        void webBrowser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser.ShowDevTools();            
            webBrowser.RegisterJsObject("MyClass", new MyClass());            

        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public void MyFunc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

--Edit Just noticed the LoadError event is fired every time with an Aborted status.  This fires whether I'm using my local HTML file or hosting Google.com.  Could this be part of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Need to Register objects directly after Browser is created as there's no on the fly binding as yet

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

At a guess your object is being registered too late. Try registering after `InitializeComponent`.

For reference there is an open `Feature Request` for on the fly binding, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/602

As for the `Aborted` error, I've seen that quite a bit with `37` even though pages load correctly. It appears to go away in version `39` (There are `-pre` releases available).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I see what your talking about now.  Hopefully that will be implemented soon.  As a workaround, I'm just using ajax requests back to my .NET application.